# Stray start tag Error

Tags: html

I have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>site title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body> 
</html>
```

firefox inform that "stray start tag `<html>`" , "stray start tag `<head>`" , "stray end tag `<head>`" and "An body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open"

how can I solve this?

please help

Comment: There may be some unprintable character present in the source that counts as character data. Since 1) the head can't contain any character data, and 2) the start tags for html, head and body are all optional, the browser concludes at that point that you want to start the body. And then it encounters the `<html>` start tag, which is, at that point, superfluous.

Comment: Where exactly is Firefox saying these things? If you right click and select "View source", do you see that exact markup?

Comment: I can't see it in your example, but one possible answer could be that you had a BOM before the `<html>` and then afterwards you added `<!DOCTYPE html>` on top, which turned the BOM into a NBZWSP.

Comment: thanks for response, firefox report this error at View source and the markup is exact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I open the page in Chrome, I get this output:

> ï»¿ï»¿

There is something strange going on in your supplied code, like unprintable characters. When I type it manually, there is no problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How did you open the page? I tried it too, but as I said above, I can't see bad things in the OP's example.

Comment: @MrLister: I copied the exact code provided by OP and pasted it in a new page on my webserver

Comment: yes this is the correct answer , but how can I remove ï»¿ï»¿ from file ?

Comment: @RamyNabiel: Retype that bit of HTML code you provided, don't copy-paste it. (Or you can copy-paste mine)